# Performance feature on player in tennis ATP matches

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have a ATP tennis games dataset.
I want to create a new feature to indicate the performance of a player on the last 10 games

But i don't know how to get the index of the row run by the apply fonction.

I tried to take all games before the selected row and filter the last ten games for the player selected. I think i have an issue with the index.

```
def ratio10(selec_joueur):
    data = df[(df['Player1'] == selec_joueur) | (df['Player2'] == selec_joueur)]
    index = df[(df['Player2'] == selec_joueur) | (df['Player2'] == selec_joueur)].index
    data[:index]
    nb_win = data.tail(10)['Winner'].value_counts()[selec_joueur]
    ratio =nb_win/(10)

    return selec_joueur


df["ratio10_P1"] = df.apply(ratio10)
```

Output I wish

```
   match_date  Player1     Player2     Winner      ratio10_P1   
  06June      Bautista     Pouille     Bautista     0.8
  08June      Anderson     Donaldson   Anderson     0.5
  07June      Zeballos     Jarry       Jarry        0.7
```

Of course then I will do the them for player 2

here is a sample of the dataframe

```
      Date      Surface  Winner             Joueur1         Joueur2
0   2000-01-03  Hard     Dosedel S.         Ljubicic I.     Dosedel S.
1   2000-01-03  Hard     Kiefer N.      Tarango J.      Kiefer N.
2   2000-01-03  Hard     Gaudio G.      Luxa P.         Gaudio G.
3   2000-01-03  Hard     El Aynaoui Y.  El Aynaoui Y.   Dupuis A.
4   2000-01-03  Hard     Cherkasov A.   Cherkasov A.    Arazi H.
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you please add a short sample of your dataframe?

Comment: Inside the apply function you almost certainly don't want to refer to `df`. But please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), with small sample input data and expected output.

Comment: here is a sample of the dataframe

Answer (score 0):

Consider reshaping data frame from [wide to long](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html) to better aggregate your data:

```py
wide_df = (
     df.rename(
         {"Player1": "Player_1", "Player2": "Player_2",
          "Winner": "Winner_1"}, 
         axis = "columns"
     ).assign(Winner_2 = lambda x: x["Winner_1"])
)

long_df = (
     pd.reshape_wide_to_long(
         wide_df,
         stubnames = ["Player", "Winner"],
         i = "match_date",
         j = "num"
     ).reset_index()
)
```

Then, calculate game count for last 10 games with [**`groupby.cumcount`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) and summing up with winning games by each player:

```py
long_df = (
    long_df.assign(
        ratio_10 = lambda x: x["Player"].eq(x["Winner"]).astype("int")
    ).sort_values(
        ["match_date", "Player"], ascending = [False, True]
    ).assign(
        game_count = lambda x: x.groupby(["match_date", "Player"]).cumcount().add(1),
    ).query("game_count <= 10")
    .groupby(["match_date", "Player"])["ratio_10"].sum().div(10)
)
```

<sup>Note: Above is not tested on actual data. Please adjust as needed.</sup>